# Sharepoint 2010 - List Pagination Settings

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, page-layout

I've been Googling my rear off and I think the issue is that the search terms are just too broad for what I'm asking.

My users are complaining that the default pagination method (lists, libraries, web parts) is cumbersome; they would like to see how many pages there are, or have options for skipping ahead to a page other than the "next" or "previous" options.  I had an image for this, but I'm a n00b and can't attach it.  :)

I am sure that this issue has been discussed and I wish I could find what I was looking for.

Any help/pointers are hugely appreciated.  Thanks for the space.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of extra options to complete the picture.

1- You could use a Content Query WebPart with Pagination that Waldek put together first for SP2007 and later on for SP2010. http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/

2- You can download Waldek's code and extend his webpart with new functionality. You could also just extend the CQWP out of the box and build your own paging. I wrote an article some time ago explaining how you could extend the CQWP and create your own XSLT functions... for instance to create the paging... http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/05/create-your-own-xslt-functions-using-c.html

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the most part pagination is totally seperate and controlled by the XSLT for the place you are viewing.

You have two options,

JQuery and the Client Object Model, making custom templates (Modifying what you have in place for this already, pretty straight forward but long winded there is a lot to edit).

or

Alter the xslts to handle the pagination, less work but maybe a little more difficult.

For ease of development, and better UI I almost always opt for using the Client Object Model with Jquery, you will need to use custom templates for this, however I have never altered data view on this scale before in SharePoint. It's a pretty large task.

Comment: I think what I'm getting out of this is that unless my users can't do their jobs, this is a low priority.

BIG thanks for the information.